# I2C on atmega328p

Tags: c, atmega, i2c, twi

I'm trying to run a I2C device using  the atmega328p (on a custom board ). I've read the data sheet , and wrote the code "exactly" as show in it: here's the code :

```
#define F_CPU 1000000
#define SCL_CLOCK 50000
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR    F_CPU/8/BAUD-1
#define TWIMUX  0x1C 


#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <util/twi.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>


// printf to debug 
static int uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream);
static FILE mystdout = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar, NULL,_FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
// initializing the UART 
void init_uart(unsigned short uValue  ){
    // setting the baud rate
    UBRR0H =(unsigned char)  ( uValue>> 8);  // 0x00
    UBRR0L =(unsigned char) uValue;  // 0x0C
    // enabling TX & RX
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0);
    UCSR0A = (1<<UDRE0)|(1<<U2X0);
    UCSR0C =  (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);    // Set frame: 8data, 1 stop

}

void init_i2c(void ) {
     uint8_t   twst;
     TWSR = 0;                         // no prescaler
     TWBR = ((F_CPU/SCL_CLOCK)-16)/2; 
     TWCR = (1<<(TWINT))|(1<<TWSTA )|(1<<TWEN);
     printf("TWCR 0x%x \n",TWCR);
     while(!(TWCR & (1<< TWINT)));
     printf(" Start condition has been transmitted \n");
     if( (TWSR&0xF8) != TW_START){
         printf(" Error \n");
     }
     // Setting Address 
     TWDR = 0x1C; 
     // cleating TWCR 
     TWCR = (1<<TWINT) |(1<<TWEN);
    if ((TWSR & 0xF8) != TW_MT_SLA_ACK){
         printf(" Error at TWSR   0x%x\n", TWSR);  // here is the problem !!!!!!!!!  TWSR value should be 0x18
         return; 
    }       
 }


static int uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream)
{
    if (c == '\n')
    uart_putchar('\r', stream);
    while ( !( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) );
    UDR0 = c;
    return 0;
}
int main(void)
{
    unsigned short i = 0 ; 
    // UART init and printf 
    init_uart(MYUBRR);
    stdout = &mystdout;
    sei();
    init_i2c();


    while(1){

    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: output]

As you can see in the output I have an error by the **TWSR** value ! 
first I  tought that the frequency isn't set correctly , but I've measure it and it definitly 50khz. I've measured SDA and SCL and here is the scope pic : 
[image]

as far as I've learned, both wires should be on high ? I've plugged an arduino board on this chip and it did work fine! so the problem is definitely in the configuration,( my code ).

any idea how might solve this ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: Please add schematics of your custom board. Also make sure that you correctly send address, it looks like you could have made a mistake interpreting address in datasheet as 8bit though suppliers usually use 7bits

Comment: Have you external pull up resistors (10k) on your SDA and SCL lines? They are necessary.

Comment: I have a 4,7k and with the arduino it works fine !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line:

```
TWCR = (1<<TWINT) |(1<<TWEN);
```

You need to wait for the TWINT bit to set:

```
while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
```

This on stage 4 in table on page 216 of the datasheet.

Without this line, your code is checking for the ACK at the *start* of transmit, not when it has completed.

In general, whenever you do anything that changes the state of the i2c bus (sending a start bit, sending an address, sending/receiving data), you should wait until the i2c hardware signals it has processed that change and is ready to continue.

Comment: it did help but now I have a new error thanks